# How allows ShowDialog in child of MdiContainer?

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

I have a form that `this.IsMdiContainer = true`. I show a child form in it.

```
 FrmCustomer frm=new FrmCustomer();
 frm.MdiParent = this;
 frm.Show();
```

I want to showdialog a form in FrmCustomer . I use this code,

```
  FrmCustomerDetail frm=new FrmCustomerDetail(null);
  frm.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
  frm.ShowDialog();
```

but i get error,

> Form that is not a top-level form cannot be displayed as a modal
>   dialog box. Remove the form from any parent form before calling
>   showDialog.'

Comment: leave out the `frm.MdiParent = this.MdiParent` and it will work. You cannot `ShowDialog` MdiChildren

Comment: @GuidoG Thanks, but i want to show form in mdicontainer.

Comment: Explain what you mean with  `but i want to show form in mdicontainer`

Comment: when i use showdialog only, The form is displayed outside the container

Comment: That is the purpose of ShowDialog. It cannot be altered easy

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055854/showdialog-in-mdi) can help you, but read the answer carefully because the solution introduced another problem it seems

Comment: [Here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23743/Movement-Restricted-Dialog-Form) is another one.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to leave our the MdiOwner and set the Window Owner using ShowDialog method parameter.

```
   FrmCustomerDetail frm=new FrmCustomerDetail(null);
   frm.ShowDialog(this);
```

Comment: Than explain what you mean with that. In my opinion this is a correct answer, if you want something different then please edit your question and elaborate more what you want

Comment: You can't use Form.ShowDialog on MDI containers.